# ESXi 6.0 Consolidation

Tags: vmware-esxi, snapshot, consolidation

I had a snapshot that had eaten the free space in a datastore. I deleted the snapshot and now the snapshot manager is empty but I see delta disks and disks such as -0002.vmdk,... -0005.vmdk etc are still in the datastore.  I made consolidation (as it recommends in such cases) but get an error

[image: Consolidation error]

So I restart services with `servises.sh restart`. It completed successful but I still can't consolidate the VM disks and to free the space in the datastore.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you follow [the VMware KB article](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/10051) to find out what is locking the file? And why are you using such a outdated version of ESXi?

Comment: How long were the snapshots lying around that they got that big - you know they're not a backup and shouldn't be left in place for more than a few days right?